# ZF2: How can I set basePath to be the same for a whole application?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules

The manual's example shows how to set the basePath only for some specific `viewModel`:

```
$this->getHelper('basePath')->setBasePath()
```

But I want to set it somewhere in one place and then it is the same for any `viewModel` I create in any Controller. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

You could set a global base path in config:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => '/path/'
)
```

Comment: Thank you vary much, it works. But how do you know that there is such a key/value pair? Here's an example from the manual how the `view_manager` config has to look like and there is no such a key `base_path` http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration. Where is it possible to see all possible keys for `view_manager` and other services?

Comment: Actually I read source codes for most times because zf2 documents are not very completely yet. You could try to grep 'view_manager' in zf2 project and will get all possible keys.